# How do I get the session property appended to the req object using Auth0 and passport with a MERN app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, auth0, mern

I'm working on an existing MERN application and I'm having trouble with auth0 and passport. From what I can tell, auth0 provides authentication and redirects back to my server. However, the `user` property that should be appended to the req object doesn't seem to get added, which I believe should be occurring in the `serializeUser` function. This is someone elses' codebase, so I'm not 100% familiar with it, nor can I consult with the programmer to ask questions.

I will list my code below and try to narrate my way through it to explain my thought process. I've tried searching similar questions and tutorials online, but no answer has presented itself yet.

Here is the `app.js` file:

```js
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const express = require('express')
const session = require('express-session')
const logger = require('morgan')
const passport = require('passport')
const cors = require('cors')
require('dotenv').config()

// connect to the database and define models
require('./db/config')
require('./models')

// require the router modules
const adminRouter = require('./routes/admin')
const authenticationRouter = require('./routes/authentication')
const challengeRouter = require('./routes/challenge')
const codeRouter = require('./routes/code')
const configRouter = require('./routes/config')
const feedbackRouter = require('./routes/feedback')
const hintRouter = require('./routes/hint')
const postAuthenticationRouter = require('./routes/postAuthenticationRouter')
const submissionRouter = require('./routes/submission')
const standingRouter = require('./routes/standing')
const userRouter = require('./routes/user')

const app = express()

// configure express
app.use(logger('dev'))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser())

// configure express-session
const { SESSION_SECRET } = process.env
const sessionConfig = {
  secret: SESSION_SECRET,
  cookie: {},
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
}

if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  sessionConfig.cookie.secure = true
}

// prevent status 304
app.disable('etag')

// import passport-auth0 strategy
const auth0Strategy = require('./passport/auth0')

app.use(session(sessionConfig))

passport.use(auth0Strategy)

// load passport strategies
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

// gets run after successful Auth0 authenticated login
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
})

// gets run for each subsequent request after logging in
passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated()
  next()
})

// allow CORS
const corsOptions = {
  origin: process.env.REACT_SERVER,
  credentials: true,
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))

// authentication middleware
const authCheckMiddleware = require('./middleware/auth-check')

// tell express which router to use based on endpoint
app.use('/api/v1/admin', authCheckMiddleware, adminRouter)
app.use('/api/v1/challenge', authCheckMiddleware, challengeRouter)
app.use('/api/v1/code', authCheckMiddleware, codeRouter)
app.use('/api/v1/config', authCheckMiddleware, configRouter)
app.use('/api/v1/feedback', authCheckMiddleware, feedbackRouter)
app.use('/api/v1/hint', authCheckMiddleware, hintRouter)
app.use('/api/v1/standing', authCheckMiddleware, standingRouter)
app.use('/api/v1/submission', authCheckMiddleware, submissionRouter)
app.use('/api/v1/user', authCheckMiddleware, userRouter)
app.use('/api/v1/postAuthentication', postAuthenticationRouter)
app.use('/', authenticationRouter)

module.exports = app
```

The `app.js` file gets imported into the `www` file, which completes the back-end server setup:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('backend:server');
var http = require('http');

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3334');
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

The auth0 strategy used is imported from the `auth0` file:

```js
const Auth0 = require('passport-auth0')
const User = require('mongoose').model('User')

const {
  AUTH0_DOMAIN,
  AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
  AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
  AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL,
} = process.env

module.exports = new Auth0(
  {
    domain: AUTH0_DOMAIN,
    clientID: AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: `${AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL}/authenticated`,
    scope: 'openid email profile <proprietary-url-1> <proprietary-url-2>',
  },
  // After Auth0 authentication, update user info in MongoDB
  // to ensure it remains sync'd with Auth0's source of truth
  async (accessToken, refreshToken, extraParams, profile, done) => {
    try {
      const userData = {
        auth0Id: profile.id,
        username: profile.nickname,
        displayName: profile.displayName,
        last_login: new Date(),
        roleType: profile._json['<proprietary-url-1>'],
      }
      let user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { auth0Id: profile.id },
        userData,
        {
          new: true,
        },
      )
      if (user) return done(null, user)
      user = await User.create(userData)
      return done(null, user)
    } catch (err) {
      return done(err)
    }
    return done(null, profile)
  },
)
```

I've tried commenting the try...catch block out above and inserting a `console.log(profile)` in its place and received no output.

In `app.js` the code imported in `app.use('/', authenticationRouter)` is:

```js
const express = require('express')
const passport = require('passport')
require('dotenv').config()

const router = express.Router()
const {
  AUTH0_DOMAIN,
  AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL,
  AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
  REACT_SERVER,
} = process.env

// Pass user authentication off to Auth0
router.get(
  '/login/auth0', 
  passport.authenticate('auth0', {
    scope: "openid email profile"
  }))

// This route gets called once Auth0 has successfully authenticated the user
router.get('/authenticated', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('auth0', (passportAuthErr, user) => {
    if (passportAuthErr) return next(passportAuthErr)
    if (!user) return res.redirect(`${REACT_SERVER}/login`)
    return req.logIn(user, (loginErr) => {
      if (loginErr) return next(loginErr)
      const { returnTo } = req.session
      delete req.session.returnTo
      return res.redirect(returnTo || `${REACT_SERVER}/authenticated`)
    })
  })(req, res, next)
})

// Perform session logout and redirect to homepage
router.get('/logout/auth0', (req, res) => {
  req.session.destroy(() => {
    res.redirect(`https://${AUTH0_DOMAIN}/v2/logout?returnTo=${AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL}/deauthenticated&client_id=${AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}`)
  });
});

router.get('/deauthenticated', (req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie('connect.sid')
  res.json({ success: true })
})

module.exports = router
```

Which redirects to `postAuthenticationRouter.js` when it comes back from Auth0:

```js
const express = require('express')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const router = express.Router()
const { JWT_SECRET } = process.env

// This route gets called by the client once it has been
// redirected to /authenticated locally (after Auth0 authentication)
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session)
  if (!req.session?.passport?.user) {
    console.log('error!!')
    return res.status(400).json({
      success: false,
      message: 'Authentication failed!',
    })
  }
  const {
    nickname: username,
    _id: userId,
    role: roleType,
  } = req.session.passport.user
  const payload = {
    sub: req.session.passport.user._id,
  }
  const token = jwt.sign(payload, JWT_SECRET)
  const userData = {
    username,
    userId,
    roleType,
  }
  return res.json({
    success: true,
    message: 'You have successfully logged in.',
    token,
    user: userData,
  })
})

module.exports = router
```

The output from the `console.log(req.session)` gives me the session object, but there is no passport property in it. I added the conditional chaining question marks and the `console.log('error!!')` to make sure I was at least getting this far, which I am because the `error!!` gets logged. But then I can get no further.

So, if I can figure out how to get the `session` object appended to the `req` object once the redirect comes back from Auth0, I can move on with this project.

Comment: Have you tried `req.user` instead of `req.session.passport.user`? This is important because if you use `req.session.passport.user`, you're essentially pulling user information out of a session cookie (which may be outdated).

Comment: It gives me a value of `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the version of nodejs I was using on my Chromebook wasn't up-to-date. Once I updated it, the project worked fine.